# .htaccess not working on Ubuntu Server x64

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I developed an application on XAMPP (Windows 8). Now i moved it to a VM with Ubuntu Server x64 and the rewriting is not working anymore.
I want always call index.php in the root folder (/var/www/html) except if the file (http://10.0.0.XX/any_path/filename) exist in the folder /var/www/html/app/web/ (like /var/www/html/app/web/any_path/filename).
This is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^[A-z/]*$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/app/web/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ app/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

On Xampp on windows it worked fine, but on Ubuntu server it doesn't seem to work anymore. `phpinfo()` says that the model mod_rewrite is loaded.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
The AccessLog and ErrorLog of apache doesn't say anything useful.

Comment: You might get better/faster/moar answers for this on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: If i don't get a proper answer here, i'll try it there. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Are you sure in `A-z`?? Moreover, the first rule, probably, will catch most of the requests. Enable mod_rewrite logging and check how everything works

Comment: I want to redirect every access to index.php if the file doesn't exist as described in the question. The problem is that if i call http://10.0.0.xx/anything it should redirect to index.php, but it shows an error that the file /var/www/html/anything is not found. On windows/xampp it worked fine (I haven't changed anything, just pulled it from git)

Comment: `if the file doesn't exist as described in the question` check at first file existence and then redirect to `index.php`, otherwise you may never reach second rewriterule.

Comment: mod_rewrite might be loaded, but it's not necessarily on. You need a bunch of `AllowOverride` and `RewriteEngine On`-type directives for anythign to actually happen.

Comment: Are htaccess files allowed in your vhost configuration?

Comment: @ Cheery The rule should be fine, it worked on two independent xampp installations fine.
@MarcB AllowOverride was set to None in apache2.conf. Thanks! Now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllowOverride was set to none in apache2.conf. Thanks to @MarcB for the hint!